# how to replace a set of lines in a file with another set of lines in unix?

Tags: shell, unix

how to replace a set of lines in a file with another set of lines in unix ?

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
export text1='log_file=$LOG_PATH${UNISON_JOB}".log"'
export text2='\. \$\{env_path\}set_test_log_file\.ksh'
export text3='log_file\=\$LOG_PATH\$\{UNISON_JOB\}\"\.log\"'

echo $text1
echo $text2
echo $text3

for file in `grep -il ${text1} SANDEEP`
do
sed 's/${text3}/${text2}/g' $file > /$file.tmp
mv /$file.tmp $file
echo $file
done
```

i tried the above code  but its not working .
its kshell .here sandeep is the file name i m searching.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to accomplish. Can you post an example of file before and after replacement?

Comment: its has not replace anything .i just trying to find text1 and replace text3 with text 2 .here text1 and text 3 are the same

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this doesn't work is because you use single qoutes for the sed command.

The sed command is trying to replace the **literal** text `${text3}` with `${text2}`.  What you want it to to is to replace the **value** of `$text3` with the value of `$text2`.

In order to use variables in the sed expression you need to use double quotes.

Another tip: if you do not need the temporary file you might as well use the `-i` option of sed to edit the file in place.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For sed with the quote, I like to write whole command into a file, then execute this file:
something like this:

```
echo "s/${text1}/${text2}/g" > a.sed
sed -f a.sed < inputFile > tmp && mv tmp inputFile
rm -f a.sed
```

that will save a lot of trouble to deal with those quote thing.