# Bash: replacing multiple consecutive lines in a file with another set of lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace

The goal is to modify some consecutive rules in an iptables file with some new rules gathered in a bash array (which could be saved into a temporary file if necessary).

The rules to modify in `rules.v4`:

```
-A ufw-user-input -s <ip_address_1>/<mask_1> -j ufw-logging-input
-A ufw-user-input -s <ip_address_2>/<mask_2> -j ufw-logging-input
-A ufw-user-input -s <ip_address_3>/<mask_3> -j ufw-logging-input
```

Those lines can be matched with: `-A ufw-user-input -s [0-9./]+ -j ufw-logging-input` or can be made available in the array `iptables_ipv4_user_input_rules[@]`

They must all be replaced in the iptables file `rules.v4` by the contents of another array containing a different set of a variable number of rules: `online_ipv4_user_input_rules[@]` or from a file containing the same lines:

```
-A ufw-user-input -s <ip_address_4>/<mask_4> -j ufw-logging-input
-A ufw-user-input -s <ip_address_5>/<mask_5> -j ufw-logging-input
-A ufw-user-input -s <ip_address_6>/<mask_6> -j ufw-logging-input
-A ufw-user-input -s <ip_address_7>/<mask_7> -j ufw-logging-input
```

I have no idea how to implement that with sed or awk.

The rules to be modified have a variable number of lines with variable line numbers, so the following post don't apply here:

- [How to search and replace multiple lines with multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612102/how-to-search-and-replace-multiple-lines-with-multiple-lines)
- [Replace multiple lines with multiple lines after finding a context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829857/replace-multiple-lines-with-multiple-lines-after-finding-a-context)
- [how to replace a set of lines in a file with another set of lines in unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735138/how-to-replace-a-set-of-lines-in-a-file-with-another-set-of-lines-in-unix)

Comment: What is the content of `online_ipv4_user_input_rules[@]` and how do you want to match the content of the file `rules.v4` with the content of the array `online_ipv4_user_input_rules[@]`?

Comment: online_ipv4_user_input_rules[@] is just another set of different rules: -A ufw-user-input -s a.a.a.a/27 -j ufw-logging-input
-A ufw-user-input -s b.b.b.b/28 -j ufw-logging-input
-A ufw-user-input -s c.c.c.c/29 -j ufw-logging-input

Comment: Is there any relation between `a.a.a.a` and `x.x.x.x`? If yes, please update your question. If not, why not just printing the content of the array?

Comment: No. It is irrelevant. They change over time in contents and number of rules/lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not so clear what you want to achieve, so maybe pasting the content of the array in the file is what you're looking at.

Assuming that the array is a `bash` array, you can use this:

```
printf "%s\n" "${online_ipv4_user_input_rules[@]}" > rules.v4
```

This will overwrite the content of the file with all elements of the array, 1 element per line.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite easy actually:

1. Removing first set of rules from rules.v4

   `sed -Ei '/-A ufw-user-input -s [0-9./]+ -j ufw-logging-input/d' rules.v4`
2. Inserting the second set of rules (previously saved into rules.tmp) after the right line into rules.v4:

   `sed -i '/-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j DROP/r rules.tmp' rules.v4`